# $|G':G''| \le p^2$ implies $G'$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is a finite $p$-group, and $|G':G''| \le p^2$, then $G'$ is an
>   abelian group.

I'm reading its proof but I cannot understand a part: Suppose $G''\neq1$, then by a theorem, there exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ contained as a subgroup of index $p$ in $G''$. Then $(G/K)'=G'/K$ and $(G/K)''=G''/K \neq 1$. So by another theorem, the center $Z/K$ of $G'/K$ is not cyclic, and so $|Z:K| \ge p^2$. **"" Hence $|G':Z| \le p$ ""**, and so $G'/K/Z/K$ is cyclic. Thus $G'/K$ is abelian, contradiction.

Why is it true that $|G':Z| \le p$?

cf. The above proof looks simple but uses other theorems a lot. Does anyone know another good proof?

Comment: Note that the order of G'/K is at most $p^3$.

Comment: @WeiZhou Why? I thought $G'/K$ has order at least $p^3&,

Comment: Well, we have $|G' : G''| \le p^{2}$ and $|G'' : K| = p$. So, $|G' : K| = |G' : G''|| G'' : K| \le p^{3}.$